# Pasting value only, Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this script that I had help with already, but now comes an issue. I am attempting to paste only the value, not the formula that is inside the cell to another cell.

I thought placing the .Value at the end of formula would tell the script to paste only the value... it seems not to be. Can someone give me a suggestion on how to make this work?

```
Option Explicit

    Sub ONJL()
        Dim lastrow As Long
        Dim wsPAR As Worksheet 'PAERTO
        Dim wsRD As Worksheet 'Raw Data
        Dim wsTEM As Worksheet 'Archive

        Set wsPAR = Sheets("PAERTO")
        Set wsRD = Sheets("Raw Data")
        Set wsTEM = Sheets("Template")


        With wsRD
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            lastrow = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            wsRD.Range("J" & lastrow + 1).Formula = Date
            wsRD.Range("B2").Copy wsRD.Range("K" & lastrow + 1).Value
            wsRD.Range("B3").Copy wsRD.Range("L" & lastrow + 1).Value
            wsRD.Range("E2").Copy wsRD.Range("M" & lastrow + 1).Value
            wsRD.Range("E3").Copy wsRD.Range("N" & lastrow + 1).Value
            wsRD.Range("H2").Copy wsRD.Range("O" & lastrow + 1).Value
            wsRD.Range("H3").Copy wsRD.Range("P" & lastrow + 1).Value
            wsRD.Range("Q1:T1").Copy wsRD.Range("Q" & lastrow + 1)
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Per your previous question and the answers to it, since the code is inside a `With` block, you should remove the `wsRD` reference from every statement inside the `With` block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can "copy" without actually using `.Copy` like this:

```
Sub CopyWithoutCopying()
    Dim wsRD As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Set wsRD = Sheets("Raw Data")

    With wsRD
        lastrow = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("K" & lastrow + 1).Value = .Range("B2").Value
        .Range("L" & lastrow + 1).Value = .Range("B3").Value
        ' etc...
    End With
End Sub
```

This approach doesn't use your clipboard, performs better, and doesn't select anything. And as Jimmy points out, you don't need the wsRD prefix inside the `With` block.

Comment: +1 but as the code is inside a With Block, you wouldn't need the `wsRD` part of the statement.

Comment: Thanks to both, I just do the wsRD as a redundancy, I know it won't matter if I take it out or not, but it's just the way I learned... more of the fact that just in case situation ;)

Comment: `I know it won't matter if I take it out or not` technically it won't, but I could easily see this approach leading to the formation of coding habits which make it harder to spot errors.